# Do I need to be memgraph user in order to run Memgraph in WSL?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've installed Memgraph inside WSL:

```
wget https://download.memgraph.com/memgraph/v2.10.0/ubuntu-20.04/memgraph_2.10.0-1_amd64.deb
```

`sudo dpkg -i memgraph_2.10.0-1_amd64.deb`

I've noticed a new user in my `/etc/passwd` (`memgraph:x:114:122::/var/lib/memgraph:/bin/bash`) and `/etc/shadow` (`memgraph:*:19587:0:99999:7:::`)

What is the purpose of this user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memgraph` user is created when you install Memgraph on Linux. It is used to run Memgraph under that user `memgraph`. I run Memgraph on my Windows laptop as part of WSL. Once I start Ubuntu I run Memgrpah with `sudo runuser -l memgraph -c '/usr/lib/memgraph/memgraph'`. I've tries running it as root, but I couldn't do it. I presume that this is done for security reasons.